# Jquery noConflict is not working in asp.net master page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have added below two scripts in master page but full calendar is working fine on clicking of below button boostrap model pop will appear but is not working

```
<a href="#" class="" > <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_btnAddOc" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-facebook pull-right" ForeColor="White" OnClick="lnk_btnAddOc_Click"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Outcome Committment</asp:LinkButton></a>
```

below is code behind c#

```
protected void lnk_btnAddOc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "LaunchServerSide", "$(function() { openModal(); });", true);


 }
```

Below are scripts of timepicker

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="OC scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="OC scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="i18n/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon-i18n.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     var jq144 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

below are calendar scripts

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="Scripts/fullcalendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
            $('#tabs').tabs();

            $('.example-container > pre').each(function(i){
                eval($(this).text());
            });
        });
        function openModal() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {


            $("#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>").click(function() 
            {
                var ProjectName = $('#<%=txt_ProjectName.ClientID%>').val();
                var MeetingTitle = $('#<%=txt_MeetingTitle.ClientID%>').val();
                var TaskDetails = $('#<%=txt_TaskDetails.ClientID%>').val();
                var datetime1 = $('#<%=txt_datetime1.ClientID%>').val();
                var datetime2 = $('#<%=txt_datetime2.ClientID%>').val();
                var datetime2 = $('#<%=txt_datetime2.ClientID%>').val();
                var ddl_Committed = $('#<%=ddl_Committed.ClientID%>').val();          

                //if (ProjectName == '') {
                //    alert("Please Enter Project Name");

                //    return false;
                //}
                if (MeetingTitle == '')
                {
                    alert("Please Enter Meeting Title");

                    return false;
                }
                else if (TaskDetails == '')
                {
                    alert("Please Enter Task Details");

                    return false;
                }
                else if (datetime1 == '') {
                    alert("Please select Review Date & Time");

                    return false;
                }
                else if (datetime2 == '') {
                    alert("Please Select Dealine");

                    return false;
                }
                else if (ddl_Committed == '') {
                    alert("Please Select Committed");

                    return false;
                }



            })
        });

    </script>
```

On button click modal pop should appear its not working when i will hide calendar scripts then modal pop is working on button click but calender is not working please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: How about replacing `$`s with `jq144`s..?

Comment: Please can you update answer for better understanding. @Teemu

Comment: Use a different function name like openModal1() or something.

Comment: ?? You're assigning a new variable name to use instead of `$`, and then you're not using the new name.

Comment: i added like openModal1()  also not working. @Atk

Comment: i added like this also    var $ = jQuery.noConflict(true); but same issue. @Teemu

Comment: I think timepicker script url are conflicting. @Teemu

Comment: Don't! See [how it works](https://jsfiddle.net/f0ngx4rw/). You should write all the non-conflicting script using `jq144` instead of `$`, how hard is that to understand ..?

Comment: ok but i think my issue  timepicker script url is conflict i think so. @Teemu

Comment: Yes, apologies but I am confused ok i will refer your link na. @Teemu

Comment: how to check your script url jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
console.log('$ is detached from jQuery, its value is ' + $);
console.log('jq is attached to jQuery, its value is ' + jq); .@Teemu

Comment: Open the console, hit F12

Comment: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6    Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (OC_Add_Committment.aspx:1200)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.4.1.js:402)
    at HTMLDocument.DOMContentLoaded (jquery-1.4.1.js:751) .@Teemu

Comment: $ is detached from jQuery, its value is function( selector, context ) {
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
 }
OC_Add_Committment.aspx:1190 jq is attached to jQuery, its value is function(a,b){return new m.fn.init(a,b)} .@Teemu

Comment: the above message and error showing on console. @Teemu

Comment: Yes, but that's not in the scope of this question. Why do you load two versions of jQuery? You could peek the [manual](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/#jQuery-noConflict-removeAll) ...

Comment: How to achieve no conflict with my script i am not getting. @Teemu

Comment: Re-write your script, start with `jq144(function(){ ...`.